# Kafka dependency between topics

Tags: dependencies, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-zookeeper

I create one consumer that subscribes to two topics, TopicA and TopicB.
When the consumer receives a message from TopicA, my business logic is to store an ObjectA into MySQL.
When the consumer receives a message from TopicB, my business logic is to update ObjectA.

But now the problem is:
TopicA and TopicB are independent from each other.
The consumer may receive a message from TopicB first and then receive a message from TopicA.
When try to update ObjectA, I find it does not exist in mysql and then a NullPointerException will be thrown.

Is there any way to configure TopicA and TopicB to make sure messages are received from TopicA first and then received from TopicB.

In another word, how can I make a dependency between topics?

Comment: How is data being sent to TopicA and TopicB? Is data guaranteed to be sent to TopicA before TopicB and you just want to read it in the right order? Or can the data be sent to TopicB before TopicA and you just want to make sure it's in TopicA before it's in TopicB?

Comment: Why do you need two different topics? Just use one topic that upserts the object.

Comment: Use one topic can solved my problem if the partition of topic is 1.But for more partitions, it still does not work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Kafka does it consume messages and produce messages based on offset. The only thing Kafka Topics can provide is the guarantee that you'll be able to consume messages in the order that they were written to Kafka. You can control how quickly you consume from a topic, but the only information that you have access to is the offset in each topic that you're at.

Saying that, your use case where you require a dependency between TopicA and TopicB doesn't seem implementable using Kafka only.

If messages are guaranteed to be written to TopicA before TopicB. You could possibly came up with a solution where both messages are written to the same topic and the first time you see a particular message you store it in MySQL and the second time you update it.

Comment: thanks a lot.Actually I have done something as you said to combine topics. But I don't think it is a better solution.Maybe I should change my design.

Comment: When I use the same topic called 'MyTopic', another problem is that there are two partitions per topic, and  this result in may consumer A receive the message with 'MyTopic' to update it first and then another consumer receive the message with same topic to create the object. It seems only the topic in one partition can keep the receive order as publish order.For example, I publish 'test message1' first and then publish 'test message2' to the topic 'Test'.If the topic has two partitions, may consumer A receive 'test message2' first and then consumer B receive 'test message1'.